# NSE puzzle: 91420512, 1297514, 35172115,?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

There's another puzzle on [nse](http://free.ultimaiq.net/nse.htm) that I don't know how to do.

```
91420512, 1297514, 35172115, ?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> 20951420

If you use

> A1Z26 conversion on your numbers,

you get

> 9 14 20 5 12, 12 9 7 5 14, 3 5 17 21 15, ?

Which translates to

> INTEL, LIGEN, CEQUO.

You’re just missing

> TIENT, which is 20 9 5 14 20, so the answer is 20951420.

Comment: did you find that on google? Ho w was that so quick!

Comment: It’s hard to explain, but whenever I see numbers that are so weirdly put together like that, this is the first thing I try. Just happened to work out this time lol, @NaeemShaikh

Comment: Wow you're a legend, all the other puzzles had no relationship to letters so I would never think of that.

Comment: @simonzack yeah, I never would of thought of what **El-Guest** did. $(+1)$ to the great answer! However, that means the question might have to (ROT13) vapyhqr gur gnt 'nycunorgvp' sbe guvf dhrfgvba, be jbhyq gung tvir vg njnl?

Comment: @user477343 Not sure, I reckon it would for me if you gave that as hint.

Comment: @simonzack agreed. Took me a minute to figure out what the sequence translated to in this answer, hahah :P

Comment: Darn. I saw it right away too, but saw the question 1 hr late :p